# How to stop gpg 2.1 spawning many agents (for unit-testing)

Tags: gnupg

I've just updated to gnupg 2.1 and the unit-tests for 0install are now running really slowly. It seems that every time I run gnupg, it spawns a new `gpg-agent` process. This takes 1 second for each test case, and the agent processes continue running afterwards:

```
$ make
Ran: 272 tests in: 26.08 seconds.
```

(normally takes about 3s)

```
$ ps x|grep gpg-agent
 8514 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-72f14da --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8543 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-19c19f2e --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8564 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-d641112 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8570 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-399201f1 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8581 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-36a69b79 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8588 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-1636a396 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8596 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-47c832e --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8602 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-3b1df330 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8651 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-7c2e2f8 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8662 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-2ecf7baa --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8672 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-3a613862 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8696 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-3dc428bc --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8704 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-324a4b7d --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8760 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-3d953fbb --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8770 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-11bab9c2 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8779 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-37699d43 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8790 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-25d40809 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8801 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-183d596b --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8811 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-1d4ed6aa --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8822 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-19587e45 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8832 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-1775543e --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8849 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-555b9f5 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8864 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-2b571a1d --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8872 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-254df8a7 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8885 ?        Ss     0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /tmp/0install-test-34930097 --use-standard-socket --daemon
 8943 pts/3    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto gpg-agent
```

How can I prevent these agent processes from starting (or otherwise make the unit-tests work properly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GnuPG 2.1 always starts the agent, even when it doesn't actually need it. As 0install doesn't require access to secret keys, I was able to fix the problem by listening on a Unix socket `S.gpg-agent` in the test directory. You need to respond to gpg as follows:

- On getting a connection, send `OK Pleased to meet you`
- Respond to `HAVEKEY` with `ERR 67108881 No secret key <GPG Agent>`
- Respond to `AGENT_ID` with `ERR 67109139 Unknown IPC command <GPG Agent>`
- Respond to all other input with `OK`.

This reduced the 0install unit-tests run time from 26s to 1.1s and there are no left-over processes at the end.

**Update for gnupg >= 2.1.13**

It no longer looks for the socket in `GNUPGHOME`. Instead, you must call `gpgconf --list-dirs` to find the location and avoid the 1s-per-unit-test time penalty. See: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2016-June/031192.html

Answer (score 0):

[GnuPG 2.1 *requires* the agent for all private key operations](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring), there is no way to disable that. Either use GnuPG 1 or 2 instead (still maintained in parallel).

The reason you're spawning lots of agents is the different home directory using the `--homedir` option, otherwise a single one would have been used. From GnuPG 2.1, all communication with the agent is performed through a socket in the GnuPG homedirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, using an older version of gpg for the tests isn't a great solution: the purpose of the tests is to check that 0install will work with the actual gpg version the user will be using.

Comment: Then you'll have to live with either the agents spawning, or use the same home directory (resulting in the tests being less separated). GnuPG 2.1 is design like this. There is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: GPG is plainly buggy.  I filed a bug about it: https://dev.gnupg.org/T3218